# SMTP and A record

Tags: wordpress, smtp, server

I am a front-end developer so the server stuff goes a bit over my head. Please excuse me if the question is dumb. 
I am hosting a wordpress site on our server with contact form 7, but we only have a A-records for www pointing to our site. The email management for said domain is held by a third party. 
How is contact form sending the emails to the admins? It is using our hosts SMTP service? I am asking because I am getting the emails on gmail, but the client is not receiving them on his service.

Thank you!

Comment: Well...where are the emails coming *from*? Have you looked at the email headers? It's impossible for us to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your server is sending email without you configuring anything, the most likely cause is that it is using the server itself. For that, it does not need to "know" any DNS entries, as it just connects to localhost, which always points to the server itself.

When you receive the mail, and your client is not, this is most likely the result of a spam filter. Have you asked your client to check the spam folder?

The problem of - mainly - shared hosting servers is that they tend to end up on spam lists like that of spamhaus.org etc. which greatly enhances your risk to end up in the spam folder. If you control the server, you could request deblocking or even whitelisting your server, but before you do that, you should be certain that your server is not inadvertedly relaying mail because of a misconfiguation, vulnerability, or outright being hacked. Your applications or the server itself could be configured to use an external smtp server, but that's not something that's easily explained here. Maybe try on serverfault.com?